# Closing a window within an activity using adb shell commands

Tags: applications, adb

I have been tinkering around with adb and attempting to control an application and close popup windows using adb shell commands. I trying to close an activity window that I can identify with the following command:

```
adb shell "dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp"
```

which returns two different variables while the window I want to close is open:

```
mCurrentFocus=Window{4e8ee3f u0 myApp/myActivity} (this is what I want to close)
mFocusedApp=AppWindowToken{ee23799 token=Token{5208e0 ActivityRecord{4dac6e3 u0 myApp/myActity}}}
```

Is it possible to close the current focus window and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to closing a dialog or a window, a user uses the Back key of their device. Through command-line you can emulate the functionality of Back key using a particular [key event](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html). The key event for Back key is [`KEYCODE_BACK`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_BACK). It has the constant value 4. Use it with *input* command in this manner:

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_BACK
adb shell input keyevent 4    # alternative
```

I recommend you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28969112) by Rene Barbosa. It lists many useful key events. I also recommend you execute `adb shell input` to find out how useful that command can be.